# Celery 4.0.0 + Amazon SQS -> "Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'queue'."

Tags: python, django, celery

I am running Celery with SQS in Django application:

When I am specifying region in broker settings like:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'sqs://'
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'region': 'eu-west-1',
    'polling_interval': 3,
    'visibility_timeout': 300,
    'queue_name_prefix':'dev-celery-',
}
```

I can see queues created in Amazon SQS but at the same time I have following error when I try to launch worker.

```
[2016-12-09 16:06:41,206: WARNING/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 318, in start
blueprint.start(self)
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
step.start(parent)
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 584, in start
c.loop(*c.loop_args())
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 88, in asynloop
next(loop)
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/async/hub.py", line 345, in create_loop
cb(*cbargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/async/http/curl.py", line 111, in on_readable
return self._on_event(fd, _pycurl.CSELECT_IN)
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/async/http/curl.py", line 124, in _on_event
self._process_pending_requests()
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/async/http/curl.py", line 130, in _process_pending_requests
self._process(curl)
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/async/http/curl.py", line 178, in _process
buffer=buffer, effective_url=effective_url, error=error,
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 146, in call
svpending(*ca, **ck)
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 139, in call
return self.throw()
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 136, in call
retval = fun(*final_args, **final_kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/funtools.py", line 100, in _transback
return callback(ret)
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 139, in call
return self.throw()
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/promises.py", line 136, in call
retval = fun(*final_args, **final_kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/funtools.py", line 98, in _transback
callback.throw()
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vine/funtools.py", line 96, in transback
ret = filter(*args + (ret,), **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/async/aws/connection.py", line 269, in _on_list_ready
raise self._for_status(response, body)
boto.exception.SQSError: SQSError: 403 Forbidden
SenderSignatureDoesNotMatchCredential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'queue'.
[2016-12-09 16:06:41,260: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to sqs://localhost//
```

It can be a bug in Celery so I have created an [issue at git](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3672).
My guess is that Celery uses legacy endpoints for SQS. New endpoints are decribed [at Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#sqs_region).

If it is not the case, please, post your solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3221)

Bug is related to not updated endpoints.json in boto. [Pull request](https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/3633) is already created but not merged.

As a workaround it is possible to load personal endpoints.json file for boto. For that you should specify the path to the file in BOTO_ENDPOINTS environment variable and load corrected file from pull request.

After correction of endpoints I solved the problem.